# Add same group to different sections of configuration fields

Tags: admin, configuration, system.xml

Can I use already defined group with a bunch of fields in different sections of system.xml without again specifying them all ? ( Like inherit the same specific group in different sections in system.xml file but with different config_path)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Magentos system.xml doesn't have any type of inheritance.